# does changing field labels impact reports?

Tags: force.com, reporting

Could changing the field label (not the API name) in anyway impact reporting in any way? I'd think that  all reports would all be backed by the API names, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. No, it will not break the reports in Salesforce. Yes, it may break integrations. It may also confuse your users, if they are not expecting it.

**Scenario:**

User exports a report for a mail merge. Changing the column names breaks pre-configured merge fields.